# Ubuntu 12.04 - Read only file system+computer crash/freezes after an update that got interupted

Tags: mount

I've run into an error with Ubuntu while I was updating it. During the update my power went out and interrupted the update. When I finally got power and booted my computer, I received an error, telling me to remount ./ and basically told me I could press S to skip or F to fix. (I forgot exactly what it said) but anyways, I originally pressed F to fix, but that didn't solve the problem, so then I went into the terminal and I tried to remount that way, but I couldn't execute because it's stuck in "file system read only."

Sorry, my description of the problem is dull. I'm debating on just reinstalling, but I have a ton of files I would like to keep, about 3+ years worth of websites I've built.

Is there a proper way to fix this?

Comment: I'm getting an error which is a status: { DYDY } error: { UNC } i tried recovery mode, but it told me to manually remount using the terminal, but i can't since i won't accept my password to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

This is what live distributions are for. Boot from a usb or cd and copy your files to another drive. Then you can reinstall, this time with a separate /home partition, so the next time you upgrade you won't lose all your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Starts with a live usb.
Open a terminal.
Identify your partitions.

```
sudo su
fdisk -l
```

Repair file systems.

```
sudo su
fsck /dev/sd??
```

Restart selecting recovery.
In the submenu select:

```
Root
Network
```

In the terminal run

```
sudo su
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```